# Why does Pycharm still refer to the old directories for my project

Tags: flask, pip, pycharm, virtualenvwrapper

Am new to Flask development and am using an IDE like Pycharm for the first time, so please pardon the ignorance.

So while playing around with a project that I am working on to understand Flask, I created a virtual environment by the name venv. So the tree of my project would look something like :

> my_project_directory
>        Project_specific_directories_and_files
>        requirements.txt 
>        venv

To activate the virtual env, I used to do venv/bin/activate and my project would run as needed.

I came across virtualevnwrapper later and decided to use that. After installing it and setting it up, I moved over to the virtualenvwrapper way of working with virtual envs and completely removed(deleted) the venv directory from my project structure. The new project structure after deleting venv is as :

> my_project_directory
>        Project_specific_directories_and_files
>        requirements.txt

Everything works fine. The project runs as expected. 
However, now after the venv directory was removed, when I open my project in Pycharm, for my import statements like :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash  # , g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchem
```

all the packages that I try importing gets underlined as error in the Pycharm IDE. I opened the Python console, in Pycharm, trying to debug the error and it gives the following error :

> Error:Cannot run program "/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/some_parent_directory/my_project_directory/venv/bin/python" (in directory "/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/some_parent_directory/my_project_directory"): error=2, No such file or directory

Now I thought that apparently Pycharm is still using it's cache. So I tried invalidating the cache and restarting Pycharm as explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html), but the problem was still there.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Why is Pycharm behaving this way? I removed the venv directory completely etc. Why is it still referencing the old (venv) location?
2. If it really is not able to resolve the dependencies, how exactly then is my project running all fine? Shouldn't it break the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After some further digging now, I was able to get the errors flagged in Pycharm rectified. I went to Pycharm -> Preferences -> Project: my_project_directory -> Project Interpreter & found that it was 'for some reason' still pointing to the older venv directory. From the drop down of the 'Project Interpreter:' section, I chose the path to my virtualenv created by virtualenvwrapper & saved the changes by Apply->Ok. This removed the error indications from the code in Pycharm. Although solved, the mystery of what/why was this happening is still unsolved for me. – qre0ct Jul 12 at 17:13

Moreover, I also removed the unused/deleted interpreters from the list of project interpreters by going to the 'more' section in the 'Project Interpreter' part and using the '-' at the bottom to remove the ones not needed.